# how to push object into jsonArray in typescript?

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript

I am trying to pushing object into existing json data in typescript, i am new to typescript, i created array variable in typescript let jsonArrayObject: boolean[] = [];and this jsonArrayObject contains contactModel object, in this object contain properties like fname,lname, id,mobile. bellow i tried code. please help me.

```
let jsonArrayObject: boolean[] = [];

jsonArrayObject=[{
    contactModel:{
    fname:"vboyini",
    lname:"simha",
    id:"1",
    Mobile:"99768999"
    }
}];
var modelData :String={
 fname:"vboyini2",
lname:"simha2",
id:"2",
Mobile:"799768999"
}
```

now i want unshift arrayitem that is contactModel object into jsonArrayObject. i tried bellow following code.

`this.jsonArrayObject.unshift({"contactModel":any=modelData})`

above code is not working. how can i push?please help me any one

Comment: this is exactly the same as arrays in javascript. though i don't see why you are declaring your objct as an array of boolean, and then overriding it with a n array of object. besides that `this.` is uneeded

Comment: each time form submit i will get contactModel object. that object i need update into jsonArrauObject , please help me

Comment: when i submit form i will get data that i will store like this 
var var modelData :String={
 fname:"vboyini2",
lname:"simha2",
id:"2",
Mobile:"799768999"
}:String={
 fname:"vboyini2",
lname:"simha2",
id:"2",
Mobile:"799768999"
}
modelData object asigning into contactModel object, this contactModel object i am pushing into jsonArrayObject,please help me

Comment: Hi @Vekant B  In `jsonArrayObject` array can have multiple objects so which object you want to unshift?

Answer (score 4):

If you need to push object into array , no need to declare it  as a boolean.

```
let jsonArrayObject = [];

jsonArrayObject.push({
  fname:"vboyini2",
  lname:"simha2",
  id:"2",
  Mobile:"799768999"
});
```

Comment: i want json object structure like this way:


Simply you can push json object into  the array like this way.
jsonArrayObject = [

 contactModel:{
fname:"ABC"
}
contactModel:{
fname:"zyx"
}
]

Comment: jsonArrayObject.push( "contactModel" :{
  fname:"vboyini2",
  lname:"simha2",
  id:"2",
  Mobile:"799768999"
});

Comment: @VenkatB Is this the object array you need ?

Comment: Did this work for you @VenkatB ? you have to add Quotation marks for "contactModel" when push into array

Answer (score 2):

First of all - you doing it all wrong.

Declare it like this:

```
    let jsonArrayObject = [];
    jsonArrayObject = [
        {
            fname: 'vboyini',
            lname: 'simha',
            id: '1',
            Mobile: '99768999'
        }
    ];
    let modelData = {
        fname: 'vboyini2',
        lname: 'simha2',
        id: '2',
        Mobile: '799768999'
    };
```

Then you can push modelData in the Array like this, or you can unshift, slice, splice and do whatever you want with the Array

```
jsonArrayObject.push(modelData);
```

Comment: now it is coming different format, it look like this:jsonArrayObject = [
  0:{fname: 'vboyini2',
        lname: 'simha2',
        id: '2',
        Mobile: '799768999'}
]
but i need bellow format
jsonArrayObject = [ contactModel:{ fname:"ABC" } contactModel:{ fname:"zyx" } ]

Comment: no I need bellow format only jsonArrayObject = [ contactModel:{ fname:"ABC" } contactModel:{ fname:"zyx" } ] , how can do in typescript

Comment: @venkat-b This is how you should write it to achieve what you want: 
let jsonArrayObject  = [{ contactModel:{fname:"ABC"}},{ contactModel:{fname:"xyz"}}] and when you parse it =>
"[{"contactModel":{"fname":"ABC"}},{"contactModel":{"fname":"xyz"}}]"

The answer is a better way, just rename the modelData

Answer (score 1):

Your scripts are showing compilation error.
Cut type of array values are set to Boolean.

```
let jsonArrayObject: boolean[] = [];
```

You need to set it to right format.

```
interface IContactModelData{
  fname:string;
  lname:string;
  id:string;
  Mobile:string;  
}

interface IContactModel{
  contactModel: IContactModelData   
}

let jsonArrayObject: IContactModel[] = [];

jsonArrayObject=[{
  contactModel:{
    fname:"vboyini",
    lname:"simha",
    id:"1",
    Mobile:"99768999"
  }
}];

var modelData:IContactModelData = {
  fname:"vboyini2",
  lname:"simha2",
  id:"2",
  Mobile:"799768999"
};

jsonArrayObject.push({contactModel:modelData});
```

Comment: contactModel property not exist in IcontactModelData error is coming

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put type in object while `unshift`ing

simply do:

```
this.jsonArrayObject.unshift({"contactModel":modelData});
```

where `modelData` is a variable.

Comment: {"contactModel":modelData} in typescript not allowing , it give error

Answer (score 0):

```
let jsonArrayObject=[];
let demo={};
demo={

    id:1,
    "name":"John Doe"
}
jsonArrayObject.push(demo);
```